# Trying to get some OpenCL code to use 2 GPUs

Tags: opencl, slurm, gpu, opencl-c

Hi I have just inherited some OpenCL code that appears to only use 1 GPU
I submit it using SLURM on a cluster and when I submit it requesting multiple nodes (typically 2)
the program just runs twice. I am wondering where I go on how to structure / restructure the code so that it can take advantage of multiple GPUs.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code that set up the OpenCL context and dispatch queue. Additionally, you should only request one (multi-GPU) node in SLURM. OpenCL does not allow you to create contexts across multiple hosts, only across multiple devices within the same host/computer/node.

Comment: As above, but if the slurm cluster is configured correctly you would have each GPU in a host configured using GRES in SLURM, then when you submit your job you would request the required resources (in this case 2 GPUs). But firslty you need to get your OpenCL running on multiple GPUs outside of SLURM.

Comment: See https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html

Comment: Hey Jan-Gerd the cluster i am working with has 1 single GPU per node IE node103 and node104  have a CPU and a GPU. Does that mean I am unable to share the processing across these 2. I will add the code this evening as well

Comment: hey @tomgalpin that is the trick getting the code written to use 2 GPUs or even a GPU and a CPU. That is where i am in the dark how do I go about parallelizing the code?

Comment: @R.Merritt - this seems to be a good explanation in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765295/using-multiple-gpus-opencl

Comment: @tomgalpin that is helpful … what I am thinking is since when I srun my program and request 2 nodes the program runs on the 2 nodes that have GPUs and submit the kernel , what I need is for the program to run on 1 nodes CPU then submit the kernel to multiple GPUs on 2 nodes...is that even possible?

Comment: ok i still am struggling here , i have code that runs on multiple GPUS if they are on the same node , the trick here is the hpc set up i have has 2 nodes with 1 gpu each what I need to do is to get the kernel submitted by the C code to submit is on the local node and use the 2 GPUs somehow. Currently the code just runs at the same time on different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two different computers on the cluster, each has one GPU and you want to distribute one task between the GPUs on different machines?

I am not aware of anything that would directly support that. In OpenCL you won't create any runtime over two computers so that is out of the game as far as I know, you need to stick to one platform. I think the same apply for CUDA.

You can however experiment with the tools https://www.open-mpi.org/ or even https://github.com/alpaka-group/alpaka designed for distributing tasks over the cluster.